# C: Incompatible pointer type on hash table

Tags: c, pointers, warnings, hashtable

I'm trying to implement a hash table and everything was fine until I define "idx" inside main (what is a must for me). Now, because "idx" is no longer a global variable, I have to use it as an argument when calling a function, and I receive the following message: "warning: passing argument 3 of 'index_createfrom' from incompatible pointer type".

What is the right way of calling a function in this case?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE_HASH_MAP 10


struct index{
    char* info;
    int line[30];
    struct index *next;
};

typedef struct index Index;


int index_createfrom(FILE* pointerToText, FILE* pointerToKey, Index **idx)
{   
    return 1;
}


int main() {

    Index* idx[SIZE_HASH_MAP] = {NULL};  

    FILE *pointerToText = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    FILE *pointerToKey = fopen("keyFile.txt", "r");

    int a = index_createfrom(pointerToText, pointerToKey, &idx); // warning here.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`idx` is a `Index**`, so `&idx` is a pointer to a `Index**` (which is to say a `Index***`).

You should pass `idx` rather than `&idx`.